# Присвоить ImageButton анимацию нажатия, как у Button

Tags: android, button

Имеется ImageButton. Как ей присвоить анимацию нажатия на нее, как у обычной Button?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте drawable-ресурс `selector` и в нем определите тип `background` у кнопки в разных состояниях. Подробнее можно почитать тут [Тайна кнопок](https://habrahabr.ru/post/206012/)